# Running bash script from Deno

Tags: bash, deno

Let’s say I’ve got this super useful and advanced bash script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo What is your name?
read name
echo What is your age?
read age
```

When I try to run it from Deno with a simple script like this:

```
const process = Deno.run({
  cmd: [`./bash.sh`],
  stdin: "piped",
  stdout: "piped",
});

const decoder = new TextDecoder();

const output = await process.output()
const parsed = decoder.decode(output);

console.log(parsed);
```

It returns nothing, but if I simplify the Deno script to the first line of the bash script it returns the output just fine

```
const process = Deno.run({
  cmd: [`echo`, `What is your name?`],
  stdin: "piped",
  stdout: "piped",
});

const decoder = new TextDecoder();

const output = await process.output()
const parsed = decoder.decode(output);

console.log(parsed);
```

Why is this? I’d assume since the start of the bash file and the single line command both start with echo it would return the same result twice

Comment: Where does your code feed anything to the stdin of the process (the pipe it's expecting to read from)? If there's no stdin, the `read`s will never complete. (If you at least _closed_ stdin, they'd fail immediately instead of hanging).

Comment: BTW, note that it's not guaranteed that a script without a shebang will be runnable at all. If you want it to be treated as a _bash_ script (as opposed to a `sh` script), that shebang should be `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, or `#!/usr/bin/bash` or such. (Typical shells have fallback behavior where they assume scripts without shebangs are shell scripts of some kind, but when something is run without a shell, that fallback isn't available, since the operating system's `execve` syscall only works with things the OS kernel knows how to execute).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I thought the `echo` would work for feeding into the stdin in. I had the shebang in my bash script but forgot to copy and paste it, I've updated the code :)

Comment: the `echo` goes to the script's stdout. Nothing here is looping it back to the script's own stdin. (If a program's stdin and stdout were automatically connected to each other, that would be... not very useful; generally, a script's goal is to take input from place-A and send output to place-B; if anything sent to place-B went back to place-A, you couldn't actually get input from outside the script, nor send output to outside the script).

Comment: Let's back up a bit: Where do you want the `read`s to get input from? When you say `stdin: "piped"`, you're telling Deno that you're going to be responsible for writing javascript code that feeds in that input. If you don't want to do that, you shouldn't be passing that parameter.

Comment: ...if, for example, you want it to prompt the user on the terminal you ran your Deno process from, you should be using the default passthrough behavior, which is what you get when you don't pass any `stdin:` argument at all.

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.5 of deno [added the `prompt`](https://deno.com/blog/v1.5#alert%2C-confirm%2C-and-prompt-added) function which allows you to completely remove the need for shelling out to a different program and handling inter-process communication via stdin/stdout.

```js
let name: string | null = null;
let age: string | null = null;

while (name === null) {
  name = prompt("What is your name?");
}

while (age === null) {
  age = prompt("What is your age?");
}

console.log(`you are ${name}, ${age}yo`);
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer but I'm just trying to figure out why I can't capture the `echo`, that's why I wrote the simple bash script to demonstrate my struggle :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is telling Deno to set up the subprocess to expect piped stdin -- but never providing it any content on stdin! Consequently, it hangs in the very first `read`.

If we take that out (letting stdin be passed through from the parent process), and do in fact answer the two prompts on the parent process's stdin, everything works perfectly:

```sh
deno run --allow-run run-bash.js <<'EOF'
A Nony Mouse
3
EOF
```

...with `run-bash.js` containing:

```js
const process = Deno.run({
  cmd: [`./bash.sh`],
  stdout: "piped",
});

const decoder = new TextDecoder();

const output = await process.output()
const parsed = decoder.decode(output);

console.log(parsed);
```

...and your `bash.sh` unchanged. `output` thus captures the two prompts (`What is your name?` and `What is your age?`), and forwards them to the javascript interpreter's stdout as-requested.

Comment: By the way, prompts intended to go to a user generally should be sent to stderr, not stdout. That's where bash itself prompts, f/e. stderr is unbuffered, whereas stdout is by default either line- or block-buffered depending on whether it's going to a TTY.

Comment: ...so if your goal was, say, to prompt the user, read data from them, and write that data to be read by the JavaScript program, I'd expect the prompts to be written to stderr, and the data (in whatever final form is selected) to be written to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `bash` to call your script
( of course with `--allow-run` option )
like :

```
const process = Deno.run({
  cmd: ["bash","bash.sh"],
  stdin: "piped",
  stdout: "piped",
});

const decoder = new TextDecoder();

const output = await process.output()
const parsed = decoder.decode(output);

console.log(parsed);
```